# Properly observing object using KVO

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view which is observing the properties of a single object using KVO. I have observed all the properties of the object in the view.

```
[person addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
 [person addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"photo" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
 [person addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"address" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

Now, when there is change in just one property, it seems to be fine but when the whole object change, the notification gets triggered 3/4 times in just fraction of seconds. I need to load the data from the network based on the changes. While a single property change creates a single network request, but if multiple properties change at the same time. It creates a queue of request for the same object. This leads to some problem. How can I observe multiple properties at the same time and load only once even if all the properties changes. 
Please do help me. This is a serious trouble, I have got into.

Comment: Keypaths are strings, not identifiers: `forKeyPath:@"name"`. Although you may have defined them as constants before, just a reminder ;)

Comment: Yes, they are indeed. I have a different case but the above is just an example to show my scenario. Well, thank you for your suggestion. ;)

Comment: I think you have to use the context parameter, unless you're absolutely sure your superclass/subclass isn't listening for the same property...

Comment: Do you mean passing the different context each time I add observer. I had the same idea, keep track of previous context and present context. Each time the notification is received, check for the context and if the request has not been made for the context, then create one. Remove the current observers and then create one with a new context. Context can be string, but can it be a dynamic and unique parameter which I can change each time I receive the notification and again start a new observation with new context value.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a dispatch source in Grand Central Dispatch to coalesce the property change observations so they aren't happening more often than you can handle them.

```
@implementation Controller
{
    dispatch_source_t source;
}
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        //We are using data add source type, but not actually using the added data.
        source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_DATA_ADD, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source, ^{
            //Insert your network call to load data from the network.
            //The event handler will only be called when another event handler is not being processed. So you won't attempt to do another network call until the last call was completed.

        });
        //Dispatch sources always start out suspended so you can add the event handler. You must resume them after creating them if you want events to be delivered)
        dispatch_resume(source);
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    dispatch_release(source);
}
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    //Tell dispatch source some data changed. It will only call the event handler if an event is not currently being handled.
    //You could add a custom timer based coalesce here for when no events are currently being processed if you want to delay all initial events to potentially wait for more changes 
    dispatch_source_merge_data(source, 1);
}
@end
```

So the first property change notification triggers the dispatch source event handler. Subsequent property changes that happen while an existing event is running are queued to run as soon as the last one is complete. This means if 5 properties change in quick succession, you will get 2 network calls (instead of 5 network calls). You can add a custom timer based coalesce when no events are being processed if you would prefer to sacrifice instant responsiveness to notifications to eliminate the second network call.

Comment: That seems like a good way to go. I thought that dispatch_source are not that important when it comes to ios. Thank you very much for the wonderful example. Will try it. Is there any good resources that point out what can be done with dispatch_source. I want to see a little bit insight. Thankyou for your quick response.

Comment: Won't this still queue up multiple events if the handler starts executing while changes are being queued? The dispatch_source docs say "If one or more new events arrive after the event handler has begun executing, the dispatch source holds onto those events until the current event handler has finished executing. At that point, it submits the event handler to the queue again with the new events."

Comment: As is common with Apple documentation, the "Concurrency Programming Guide" doesn't really spell out a lot of useful use cases. The WWDC videos however are packed full of this kind of useful recipe.

Comment: @JesseRusak No, the dispatch_source_merge_data coalesces any pending data while an event handler is running. When the event handler completes, it fires a single new event. You can receive the coalesced data through dispatch_source_get_data. However, we don't care about the coalesced data (the number is arbitrary and unrelated), we just care that it keeps the event handler from running every time a property changes.

Comment: Right; I just mean that if two properties change in quick succession, the could handler run after the first KVO notification but before the second, which will cause it to update twice when it could have just updated once. So, it's better to do the coalescing yourself with a timer or some other mechanism.

Comment: @JesseRusak I see what you are saying now. Yes, the first network call is always fulfilled immediately. If multiple properties change quickly, then two network calls happen. To optimize network calls further, he could add a timer based coalesce to decrease the number of network calls by one by delaying all initial network calls by the timer length. The question does not have enough detail to know if he is interested in further optimizing the number of network calls by sacrificing responsiveness to notifications. Updating answer to point that out.

Comment: @FruityGeek I dont think this is quite sufficient. The code works fine sometimes and load only once. But, it is very uncertain and loads many times sometimes. I would be really interested in the delaying the initial network call. I looked at dispatch_timer and tried to apply to this, but could not get it working since I have not enough idea on how dispatch_source s work. Please help me kindly for further improvement of this solution.

Comment: @NSProxy Please kindly accept the answer as it solves your problem. The area where you will need to implement a timer for further optimization has been clearly marked as a code comment in the `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`.

Comment: Could you please point me the resources to further learn about dispatch sources. I will do it myself. I am really happy for your answer and surely will accept it.